# BIDS issue converting date string

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, bids

I'm trying to fire off an RDL via KRONOS application. The problem I'm running into is passing the variables in the same format. I have a query that is selecting a date field that is formatted (DateTime,NULL).

It looks like the variables are being passed as:
                  AND inp.WK_END>= '2014 02 01 00 00 00' (this is a parameter: @to_timeframe)

```
              SQL Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider , Message: Conversion failed when                    converting datetime from character string.


      5/8/2014 1:11:16 PM RDLC Parameter 'from_timeframe' value(s): 2014 02 01 00 00 00
```

I need the above values to be:

```
   5/8/2014 1:24:02 PM RDLC Parameter 'from_timeframe' value(s): 2/1/2014 12:00:00 AM
   5/8/2014 1:24:02 PM RDLC Parameter 'to_timeframe' value(s): 5/31/2014 11:59:59 PM
```

Comment: It's unclear precisely what's going on here.  BIDS is generating the parameters for SSRS using a query to populate its parameters?

Comment: What is KRONOS? How are you "passing the variables"? What datatype is the Parameter @to_timeframe? Is the report deployed or are you somehow trying to automate BIDS/Visual Studio?

Comment: What are the data types for your two parameters? If they are datetime equivalents, the format you **really** want is "2014-02-01T00:00:00" That is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.MSS which is the ISO format for such things. Otherwise, you're going to be in the special hell reserved for those who don't defend against international date formats and those that speak in the theater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out all I had to do is go into the report parameter properties and change the data type to Date/Time... Thank you for all of your help.